# nglink not working in phantomjs component test for angular 1.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phantomjs, angularjs-1.5, ngcomponentrouter

I have a navbar component:

```js
.component('navbar', {
      templateUrl: 'app/common/navbar/navbar.html',
      controller: NavbarController,
      bindings: {
        state: '<',
        weekLabel: '<'
      }
    })

  /** @ngInject */
  function NavbarController () {
  }
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h3 class="text-muted">
    Vaccine Stock Dashboard
    <span ng-if="$ctrl.state"> - </span>
    <span class="qa-state-label" ng-bind="$ctrl.state | uppercase"></span>
    <span ng-if="$ctrl.weekLabel"> - </span>
    <span class="qa-week-label" ng-bind="$ctrl.weekLabel"></span>
    <a class="pull-right" ng-link="['NewStockCount']">
      <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
      Add Stock Count
    </a>
  </h3>
</div>
```

The test runs fine without the `ng-link="['NewStockCount']"` but if i add it fails with an error

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Map (line 2166)
>       RouteRegistry@/home/femi/fielded/nav-integrated-state-dashboard/bower_components/bower-angular-router/angular1/angular_1_router.js:2166:30

how do i correct this to make it pass with `ng-link`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after my search i realized it wasn't my code that have the issue but Phantomjs is not compatible with es6 yet. the solutions is to either bump up to Phantomjs2 or add polyfills; [here is a fantastic article on that](http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/aurelia-karma-and-more-vs-debugging-goodness)

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documention for the component router](https://angular.github.io/router/ngLink), the directive is `router-link`, not `ng-link` (even though it's called ngLink).

Comment: that's some confusion, cause the official docs say otherwise https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component-router. and i tried example from your link,didn't work. probably that's for ng2 not 1.5

Comment: Can I see the route config? Also, what order are you including the angular source files in?  Googling that error points to a potential problem with something getting loaded in the wrong order.